# Как получить элемент (страницу) из ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте!
Скажите пожалуйста, как в можно получить элемент из ViewPager для дальнейшей работы с ним?

Я пробовал получать его таким способом:

```
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpager);
        SimplePagerAdapter newAdapter = new 
    SimplePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        newAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment_1()); //Добавляем фрагмент
        viewPager.setAdapter(newAdapter);

        Fragment fragment = ((SimplePagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(0);
        Fragment_1 oneFragment = (Fragment_1) fragment;

        oneFragment.setNewText("New text"); //На этом этапе выскакивает ошибка
```

Ошибка вот: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

Я, кстати, проверил: значение **oneFragment.getView() == null**

Соответственно содержимое класса Fragment_1:

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment{
    TextView myText;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_screen_1, container, false);
    }

    public void setNewText(String text){
        myText.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        myText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_green);
    }
}
```

myText - точно не нулевой объект, если вместо строчки

```
myText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_green);
```

написать

```
myText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_green);
myText.setText("new text");
```

то все работает, текст меняется.

И адаптер:

```
public class SimplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {
    private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SimplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager mgr) {
        super(mgr);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вполне можете использовать свой код

```
Fragment fragment = ((SimplePagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(0);
Fragment_1 oneFragment = (Fragment_1) fragment;
oneFragment.setNewText("New text");
```

Но только не в методе onCreate. Т.к. фрагмент еще не инициализировал свой View. Согласно Вашему коду из фрагмента присовение `myText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_green);` происходит в методе **onStart**. Так что, пока фрагмент не перейдет в состояние **onStart**, поле **myText** будет равно **null**.

Рекомендую Вам почитать про жизненные циклы фрагмента и активити.

Comment: насколько я понял, этот код мне нужно использовать в методе onResume (в активити), однако результат не меняется (как и в onStart).

Comment: извиняюсь за прошлый комментарий. Вывел последовательность "жизненных циклов" (onCreate, onResume и т.д.) в лог, получается, что фрагменты создаются после onStart и onResume активити. Но откуда тогда обращаться к ним из активити?

Comment: Если Вы хотите присвоить какой-то текст сразу при инициализации фрагмента - передавайте этот текст при создании фрагмента ;) и после того как во фрагменте будет инициализировано вью - установите текст в Ваш TextView.

Comment: P.S. "myText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_green);" - почему Вы ищите TextView в актвити, а не в фрагменте ? 
Во фрагменте можете переопределить метод onViewCreated, он передаёт уже инициализированное вью, в котором можно искать элементы разметки myText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_green);

Comment: Согласен, просто лично для меня привычнее было бы сделать все действия над элементом (то же изменение текста) из активити, вот я и хотел узнать, а можно ли это сделать. В любом случае большое спасибо за ответ, сам я бы до такого не докопался.